# StackOverflowError while testing mleap pipeline

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, mleap

I am using mleap to serialize spark pipeline. I have also added checkpoint stages in the bundle, however, I am still facing StackOverflowError while calling transform on the pipeline, the checkpoint also seems to be working as the rdds are being saved on HDFS.

Is there any suggestion to fix this or any alternative way to perform testing on mleap pipeline without any stackoverflow or memory issues?

Comment: Could you add details like the code? Inputs and outputs expected? Metrics?